# How to send USR2 signal?

Tags: linux, nginx, signals

I read that to upgrade nginx involves among other things sending the `USR2` signal with `kill -USR2 pid`. So I tried `sudo kill -USR2 3049` but got

```
$ sudo kill –USR2 3049
kill: failed to parse argument: '–USR2'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was copy pasting from a website and that caused the wrong dash to be used.

```
sudo kill –USR2 3049
```

vs the correct dash (hypen):

```
sudo kill -USR2 3049
```

Comment: Beware that the sign in the code above is a dash which will raise a `failed to parse argument error` if copy-pasted into a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

First invoke `kill -l` to list all signals

in some destro `USR2` is `SIGUSR2`.  also you can run it by it's number

Comment: `kill -l` showed `SIGUSR2` but when I did `sudo kill –SIGUSR2 3049` it still gave back `kill: failed to parse argument: '–SIGUSR2'`

Comment: If you get the `failed to parse argument error` it is because you copied the code which contains a dash `–` instead of a negative sign `-`

Answer (score -8):

Where you read such thing?
if your goal is to restart nginx after an upgrade just run

```
killall -9 nginx && service nginx start
```

or

```
service nginx restart
```

Comment: this "Upgrading (nginx) Executable on the Fly" indicates to send a USR2 signal --> http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine#Upgrading_To_a_New_Binary_On_The_Fly

Comment: kill -9 is almost never a good idea, unless a process is just not responsive to the plain kill signal.